# Floats not working with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying two float two elements with inside a Bootstrap navigation, but it won't work.

```css
.cls1 {
  float: left !important;
}

.cls2 {
  float: right !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse5" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle cls1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="cls2">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-tumblr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-vimeo-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-rss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse5" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NATURE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TRAVEL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MUSIC</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Am I missing something? Is there a conflict that I am not seeing?

Comment: which bootstrap version?

Comment: I would suggest you to use pull-right and pull-left class of bootstrap

Comment: Why do you have: `hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg` in <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
Because of this whole navbar is not visible on bigger screens

Comment: In what way is the snippet not working? The div with class cls2 is floated to the right, as instructed.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch 3.3.7

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers let me try that

Comment: @KenanBalija Because I don't want it to appear on large screen

Comment: @MrLister i switch left to right and right to left and it still won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

there is class .hidden-lg it have css style

```css
@media (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 992px)
.hidden-md {
    display: none!important;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.hidden-lg {
    display: none!important;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px)
.hidden-sm {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Because of these bootstrap classes, the whole element should be hide from DOM. Below 768px of window size it should work.

Below edit the code and try it

```css
.cls1 {
  float: left !important;
}

.cls2 {
  float: right !important;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .cls3 {
  float: right !important;
 }
 .cls2 {
  display:none;
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse5" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle cls1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
 <div class="cls3 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-tumblr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-vimeo-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-rss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>      
    </div> 
    <div id="navbarCollapse5" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NATURE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TRAVEL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MUSIC</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 <div class="cls2">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-tumblr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-vimeo-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-rss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: am sorry but your solution did not make much sense for me.